# Show that a function is a contraction...

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show $f:(1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} (x+\frac{a}{x})$ is a contraction when $a\in(1,3)$.

My attempt:
$|f(x)-f(y)| = |\frac{1}{2} (x+\frac{a}{x}) - (\frac{1}{2} (y+\frac{a}{y}))| = \frac{1}{2}|x+\frac{a}{x}-y-x+\frac{a}{y}| = \frac{1}{2}|x+\frac{ay}{xy}-y-\frac{ax}{xy}|= \frac{1}{2}|x-y+ a(\frac{y-x}{xy})| \leq \frac{1}{2}|x-y| + \frac{a}{2}|\frac{x-y}{xy}| \leq \frac{1}{2}|x-y| + \frac{a}{2}|x-y| = \frac{a+1}{2}|x-y|$.

Unfortunately, $\frac{a+1}{2}$ does not have to be less than 1, so it doesn't work. Is there any way I can get a tighter bound? I have looked into some theorems about contractions but would like to use just the definition if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Take $x, y$ close to $0$, say $x = 10^{-10}$ and $y = 10^{-100}$, the difference between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ is so large that its absolute value is much much larger than $|x-y|$ which is close to $0$. So $f$ is not a contraction on $(0, +\infty)$

But if we restrict $f$ on $(1, +\infty)$, we can have  $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{a}{2x^2}$ and $$\frac{1}{2} - \dfrac{a}{2} < f'(x) < \dfrac{1}{2}$$ when $x > 1$ and $a > 0$

Since $a \in (1,3)$, we can say $|f'(x)| < 1$, so $f$ is a contraction on $(1, +\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

Using the mean value theorem: as $$|f'(x)| = \frac 12 \left|1 - \frac a{x^2}\right|$$is not bounded, the function is not Lipschitz and hence not a contraction.

Of you restrict it on $[b,\infty)$ then
$$
|f'(x)| \le \max \left(\frac 12 \left|1 - \frac a{b^2}\right|, \frac 12
\right)
$$

so the function is a contraction as soon as
$$
\left|1 - \frac a{b^2}\right| < 2
$$